# Mac Word keeps popping in front of the active application

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I'm using MS/Word 2011 (14.5.0) on Mavericks; I use an external monitor plus the MacBook monitor. Whenever I {Cmd-Tab} to an app that's on the same monitor as Word, it forces itself to the front, getting in the way of the app I just switched to. Really annoying -- a real focus-buster. I've found that I can simply "Hide Word" {Cmd-H} but I'd prefer to tell Word to behave nicely.

Any way to do that? Preferences didn't appear to have anything useful...